# Terraform: include parent folder tf files when running "terrafrom plan or apply"

Tags: terraform

Thanks in advance

Here is the folder structure
[image: example]

How do I include kms.tf, variable.tf, and providers.tf when I run the command "terraform init, plan, apply" from folder Dev or Prod?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from tricks at a lower level of abstraction, such as creating symbolic links which might cause Terraform to find the same files in multiple locations due to underlying OS behavior, there is no way to achieve what you have described.

A fundamental assumption in Terraform is that a module consists of a single directory containing one or more `.tf` or `.tf.json` files. Any `.tf` files that are in other directories by definition belong to separate modules, and so if you wish to include those in your configuration you will need to call those other modules using [`module` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/syntax).